# Embed iframe in Apple News Format

Tags: apple-news

I am trying to embed an iframe in Apple News Content and have problem with it.

According to [Apple News Format documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Apple_News_Format_Ref/HTMLMarkupforAppleNewsFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015408-CH110-SW1), it seems not allowed to embed iframe in Apple News Content.

But I saw many sample news that have an embedded iframe.

Does anybody have this experience?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to embed iframes in ANF. Apple supports a few components out of the box, such as maps, social posts, videos, html table and a few others. Full list here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/apple_news_format/components